# Protocol-Buffers: How to exclude code generation during build time in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, protocol-buffers

We have a few `.proto` files from which java classes are generated.

Because we have to keep the generated files in the repository, we would like to generate them only when we want (and not during every single build ). We are using [this](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) plugin. Also we would like to stick with this plugin, since we have quite a few things configured and we found it pretty useful.

Is there a way to exclude code generation during `build` task in gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable protobuf tasks based on the property passed via command line:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

protobuf {
  generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
            task.enabled = project.hasProperty('runProtobuf')
    }
  }
}


afterEvaluate {
  println "generateProto enabled ${tasks.generateProto.enabled}"
  println "generateTestProto enabled ${tasks.generateTestProto.enabled}"
}
```